# Poker Hand Evaluator Array of Structures

Tags: c#, poker

For a task I have been asked the following:

Write a program that evaluates a single poker hand.  Display the hand and print out what type it is. The ranks of hands are listed below from highest ranking to lowest ranking.
Use a structure for the card, and an array of structures for the hand. You should write a method for each type of hand, returning true if the hand fits that criterion, and false if it doesn’t.
The structure you will use should look something like the following:

```
public struct card 
{    
    public char suit; // 'C', 'D', 'H', 'S' - for clubs, diamonds, hearts, and spades    
    public int value; //2-14 – for 2-10,Jack, Queen, King, Ace 
};   

struct card hand[5];
```

External txt files have been assigned for us to use that appear like this :

C 13 H 13 D 13 C 10 H 10

I have managed to read the text files into my program, but I am unsure as what to do with this. The array of structures would be like:

(C 13)(H 13)(D 13)(C 10)(H 10)

Not quite sure how to transfer the line of text from the file into this type of format, any help is appreciated, cheers :)

Comment: Is it your homework? -1

Comment: Yes, why wouldn't it be ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.SqlClient;

namespace ConsoleApplication45
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            List<Card> cards = new List<Card>();
            string input = "C 13 H 13 D 13 C 10 H 10";
            string[] inputArray = input.Split(new char[] {' '}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);

            for(int i = 0; i < 10; i += 2)
            {
                Card newCard = new Card();
                newCard.suit = inputArray[i][0];
                newCard.value = int.Parse(inputArray[i + 1]);
                cards.Add(newCard);
            }

            foreach (Card card in cards)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Suit {0}, Rank {1}", card.suit, card.value.ToString());
            }
            Console.ReadLine();


        }
        public struct Card
        {
            public char suit; // 'C', 'D', 'H', 'S' - for clubs, diamonds, hearts, and spades    
            public int value; //2-14 – for 2-10,Jack, Queen, King, Ace };
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Quite new to C#, how exactly do I get the finished card from this ? Quite tired too, stayed up all night trying to figure this out, cheers